# log4j configuration not used

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, log4j

My log4j logger does not want to use the `log4j.xml` file to be configured. This file is located in the `src` folder and looks like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\debug\myproject\logfile.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10024KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{dd-MM HH:mm:ss,SSS} (%F:%M:%L)  -%m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

But `logfile.log` is still empty and there is no `DEBUG` line in the console.

NB: it is a Java EE project on JBoss 7.1.0 and using Struts2.

Comment: how you loading log4j settings? Also show path to log4j conf inside build project

Comment: Have you tried "-Dlog4j.debug" or any of the standard well-documented ways to troubleshoot your setup?

Comment: I saw, in some posts, that log4j is looking for a log4j.properties or xml file by its own. So, I have not specieifed anything else.

Comment: Is the config file actually being deployed at the root of the classpath?

Comment: you are probably use some other logging mechanism

Comment: what does the server log say at the startup .. it should have log4j output statement ?

Comment: Make sure your log4j is on classpath. Only then the application would read it

Comment: Does the path C:\debug\myproject\ exists in your file system ?

Comment: Ok! I managed to override the level using this method: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Copying log4j.xml to lib folder is not mandatory. If the file is on classpath it would be read.

Comment: I put it next to the struts.xml and it perfectly works. So you said, it is not mandatory to put it in the lib folder.

Comment: @Florent06 Exactly!!!. struts.xml is on classpath. consecutively log4j.xml is also on classpath.

Answer (score 1):

**The following answer is not entirely mine. It was posted in the question itself by the OP, so I'm moving it into this community wiki answer.**

---

I resolved it by explicitely configuring the logging configuration.

Note that you won't be able to change the configuration at runtime if you configure it using a file.

For more information, see: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the log4j.xml file is located in the `/WEB-INF/classes` directory of your web application.

Comment: Yes it is in this directory.

Comment: .. ideally it should be outside the EAR . Your log config files location should be independent of the EAR you build and deploy. This mean that you can switch from DEBUG to INFO without building the EAR which is a lengthy process :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the log file. If you use the absolute file name make sure to replace backslashes with slash. For example

```
<param name="File" value="C:/debug/myproject/logfile.log" />
```