# Add dynamic parts in texts

Tags: java, jsp, properties, struts2, jsp-tags

When I try to put some dynamic parts in my texts to be used by `<s:text>` tag in Struts 2, these parts are replaced by the `params` I defined.

Here is how I write my sentences in my `file.properties`:

```
my_error=The event {0} doesn't exist
```

Here is how I try to display it:

```
<s:text name="my_error">
    <s:param>Event01</s:param>
</s:text>
```

But in the result, the expression `{0}` is NOT replaced and I have no error in the log. What's wrong?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Try to debug it.

Comment: I tried a lot of things to do. I tried to name the param, I try to change the charset...

Comment: Set log level to debug and see if there is any warnings.Try with `getText` method inside action class.

Comment: I don't manage to change the level. I have posted the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026408/log4j-configuration-not-used but nothing works.

I think I'm a magnet for problems

Comment: I DID change the level! But I have no warning in my log.

Comment: i too have the same problem!!!

Comment: `I think I'm a magnet for problems` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't understand. I picked this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-text-tag-example/), so I have this in my jsp file:

```
<s:text name="msg.error">
    <s:param >Event01</s:param>
</s:text>
<br />
<s:text name="name.msg.param" >
    <s:param >mkyong</s:param>
</s:text>
```

and this in my .properties:

```
msg.error = This event doesn't exist: {0}
name.msg.param = This is a message from properties file - param : {0}
```

But the result is:

```
This event does not exist: {0}
This is a message from properties file - param : mkyong
```

I do not manage to find a real difference.

Comment: Ok I found the problem!

I had a single quote in the sentence to be parsed. So I doubled it and now, it works. I've found it by erasing it from the sentence and it worked.

Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: +1. Had the same issue today, just because the **single quote wasn't repeated**, like this: `info=Person''s name is John`. P.S. Delete your comment ("Ok I found...") and put it to your answer's body, so the other users could notice it better.

Answer (score 1):

> The message must be in a resource bundle with the same name as the
>   action that it is associated with.
>
> If the named message is not found in a property file, then the body of
>   the tag will be used as default message.

Create or put the resource bundle for the locale you use to the place better described using the search order in the [localization guide](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html).

Comment: I do not use localization. And my text is displayed but "{0}" is not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

i guess {0} refers to the first index of the list that should be passed as a parameter to the getText method.

Now when you use s:text and pass the param, it should be a list type variable containing the element with value "Event01" in the first index.

Try implementing the same. It might work :)